# DocuSign REST API: Check pending envelopes for a user

Tags: docusignapi

Can I make a REST call to check the count of pending envelopes for any particular user?
What I want to achieve: 
Before deleting the user I need to make sure that user has no pending envelopes. If he has any pending envelopes then it should return the count or list of envelopes for that user.

Updated:

Re: Drew's answer

Actually, GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/ this call is returning me the folder id of my folder, but I want to check for other users folder.

for example: I am the admin, and I have 3 users in the dousign, I have my account ID from which I can Request folder ID by using (GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/) method. But if I want to know the folder id details of the remaining 3 users then how can I get that details as I won't be having their accountID's.

Please let me know if anything is possible ? I am very much trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using a specific SDK when using REST ? or are you just using a plain HTTP request with a JSON/XML payload ?

Comment: Just HTTP : JSON payload

Comment: If you are not planning to use OAUTH for all the users the please check my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46429617/3530898

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find that like this:

First, a call to `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/`

This gets me the user's Sent folder ID, so I can make a call to `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/{{folderid}}?status=sent` and `GET {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/folders/{{folderid}}?status=delivered`

totalSetSize is what you're looking for

If your users are using Folders to organize their sent items, the numbers won't be reliable and you'll need to iterate through each folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a "User Application" then the individual users should log into the app. Then when you query for envelope status you will be querying as the user. [Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html)

If you're writing a "Service Application" that will run in the background somewhere and send notifications that users have envelopes waiting to be signed (for example), then use `impersonation`.

Impersonation enables your app to impersonate a user. When it does so, your app will act on the user's behalf and be able to see the user's envelopes. [Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html)